# How to find if a windows (SQL) server is clustered or standalone?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I don't know the exact windows/SQL server terminology so I might have said things a little different than actual technical terms. Please forgive.

I am connected to a host using windows credentials which I know is a SQL-Server.
Is there a way to find if that host is part of a cluster or just stand alone server using power shell/bash?

For example there are two nodes NODE_1 & NODE_2 that form a cluster and has 4 hosts named host_1, host_2, host_3, host_4. All these hosts are SQL - Servers. When I connect to any of these hosts using windows credentials and run hostname on bash, I get either (NODE_1 & NODE_2).

I tried following power-shell (on host_1 -> NODE_1) but it always says host is not clustered:

```
$server = hostname; # Tried commenting this line. $server still gets 'NODE_1'
$s=Get-WMIObject -query "select * from Win32_ComputerSystem" -ComputerName $server | select name
if ($s.Name -ne $server) { 
#if ($s -ne $server) {
Write-Output "$server is clustered"
} else {
Write-Output "$server is not clustered"
}
```

I think this because I am assigning node name 'NODE_1' to $server instead of 'host_1'. But I am unable to find a way to get 'host_1' using power-shell.

**What I have tried:** Replacing $server with 'host_1' manually gets correct result. But as this script will be part of a larger program that'll run on hundreds of SQL servers with different versions, I can't manually provide actual host-name as string. So I am trying to find a way to do this using power-shell.

I also tried these options to get 'host_1' but they all return 'NODE_1'.

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Env:Computername
NODE_1
PS SQLSERVER:\> hostname.exe
NODE_1
PS SQLSERVER:\> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
NODE_1
PS SQLSERVER:\> $env:COMPUTERNAME
NODE_1
```

May be host_1, host_2, host_3, host_4 are called listeners in SQL terms?

**Question:** Is there a way to get 'host_1' assigned to $server instead of 'NODE_1' using power-shell?

If there is another way to do this after making connection using windows/SQL credentials then I would definitely try it out.

Only constraint I have is I would not know if the host is clustered (and so has multiple DB instances) or standalone. So using SQL credentials might fail if I try making connection to an instance but my connection string doesn't have "$server=host-name\instance"

Comment: Since you want to use powershell... i'd use dbatools. They have developed a truck load of stuff in PS for SQL Server. https://dbatools.io/

Comment: Thank you for your response scsimon. But unfortunately we don't own the servers so won't have access to install anything new. An convincing the owner team ia a long path :-)

Comment: but you's just using powershell scripts... regardless if you they are custom or open source I don't see what the issue would be. That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Cluster Service is present **and** if the `Get-Cluster` cmdlet returns output.

```
if ( (Get-Service -Name ClusSvc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -AND (Get-Cluster -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ) {
    Write-Output "Clustered"
} else {
    Write-Output "Standalone"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, $HostName can be the cluster name or the name of one of the nodes.  It can be hardcoded instead of the variable used in this example.

```
$services = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SystemServices -computername $HostName
foreach ($service in $services.partcomponent) { if ($service -match 'ClusSvc') { 'Clustered' }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Bruce. But when I try this I get error:
`PS C:\Users\user> $services = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SystemServices -computername $HostName


Get-WmiObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:69
+ $services = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_SystemServices -computername $HostName
+                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: Did you set $Hostname to a valid Windows host?